# curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553 to vsftpd docker

Tags: ftp, docker, curl, upload, vsftpd

I'm running you container and try to send files using `curl` but it fails.

#### Running the container

```
export FTP_USER="test"
export FTP_PASSWORD="test"

docker run \
    --name mock_ftp_server \
    --publish 21:21 \
    --publish 4559-4564:4559-4564 \
    --env FTP_USER="$FTP_USER" \
    --env FTP_PASSWORD="$FTP_PASSWORD" \
    --detach \
  panubo/vsftpd
```

#### Sending file

```
$ curl --upload-file /tmp/mock.data-2017-03-28.tar.gz ftp://localhost --user $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553
```

#### Question

What's the matter here? Do I need to add something?

**related**

- [How to upload one file by FTP from command line?](https://superuser.com/q/323214/174465) @ SuperUser
- [curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553](https://github.com/panubo/docker-vsftpd/issues/1) @ Github
- [curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 553 to vsftpd docker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/354450/17362) @ Unix&Linux

Answer (score 0):

Based on [VSFTPD 553 error: could not create file on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/320186/22343) I fixed it by **changing the owner of the root directory (`/srv/`)** to the FTP user `ftp`:

```
docker run …
docker exec mock_ftp_server chown ftp:ftp -R /srv/
curl …
```

I'm [waiting for information about security](https://github.com/panubo/docker-vsftpd/issues/1) for this solution.